# Are multidimensional arrays in java useful?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out where you would use a multidimensional array. For example where would you ever need to use an array such as

int x [][][][]  ?

Comment: You'll probably never use a multidimensional array in real code, unless you're doing math or (maybe) if you're working with images.

Comment: Ok sweet, just cause it's confusing to figure out what it would look like, so I was stressing about needing to use them later on. Thanks

Comment: You might run in to some 2+ dimensional data structures more generally, though, like lists of lists (of lists...). It's just especially uncommon to see any kind of *array* in real code. This is a good video if you want to conceptualize what higher dimensions are like in general: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkF73zv8qas.

Comment: You can always argue that something at its extreme is useless (e.g. `List<List<List<List<List<List<T>>>>>>`, but 2/3 dimensional arrays are certainly used quite often (2 for e.g. a matrix).

Comment: Man I get why this question got canned but the first answer on this is worse. Matrices are super useful. You have

Comment: Man I get why this question got canned but the first answer on this is worse. Matrices are super useful. Say you want to build something multiple ways - I recently used one in to construct a mapping. Like if you wanted to calculate the Cartesian product of 3 sets. Example - if I wanted to package something for multiple versions, supporting java software versions for multiple OS’s. You can iterate over and combine them all, constructing a mapping of the stages and execute in parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common use for multi dimensional arrays is if you are working in dimensions. For example, if you are loading an image, you can store a byte for every location of that image in a `byte[][]` array so you can access each pixel with an x y coordinate. Or for any grid in that matter, this could be used, such as a spreadsheet or a Tic Tac Toe board.

In game development, you can use a 3-dimensional array in order to represent points in 3D space. This could be used to represent a model or parameters of a camera using matrices.

For data storage, you can use multidimensional arrays of even larger sizes to represent chains of data structures or matrices for matrix math which have a slur of their own uses. For example, if you had 500 people, represented by numbers who all did 500 courses, 500 papers, and 500 tests, you can use `people[200][200][200][200]` to get the test results of the 200th person who did the 200th course who did the 200th... etc. However, in OOP, this could be done with objects instead.

For all these uses, there are OOP or other tricks to replace them. It all comes down to whichever you feel is the easiest for you to work with.

Comment: In Java, it would be unlikely that real image processing code would use multidimensional arrays, though, because their cache performance is bad.

Comment: Interesting, do you know what kind of structure is Java using when I call #getPixelReader#getColor? @Radiodef

Comment: The image processing code that I've seen uses a regular 1D array and uses `a*b+c` to access it like a 2D array. (Plain arrays are contiguous in memory but multi-dimensional arrays are not.) Maybe that's splitting hairs a little, but the question is a little vague about whether it's about arrays in particular or data structures more generally.

Comment: That 500x500x500x500 matrix will have 500^4 elements -- that's 62,500,000,000. If they're each represented by an int, that's about 250 GB of memory right there. Just sayin. :-)

Answer (score 2):

They are very useful if you need them. For example, you could be dealing with 3D objects (x,y,z) coordinates or for mathematical research. Usually, you will not use them on a daily bases as a programmer. Oh, in case you didn't know, the maximum number of dimensions Java allows is 255.